# Is it possible to package an Erlang program as a .exe file?

Tags: erlang, exe

It has to be self contained, some sort of Erlang runtime library, and the BEAM files. This is so that anyone can run the program with one click, by running a .exe off a network drive, without having to install Erlang or anything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795628/erlang-compilation-erlang-as-stand-alone-executeable

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, you would deploy the emulator and everything that's needed from the standard library as well as your application alongside it. Wings3D does that, too.

The `reltool` application can help you with that. You can also pack your beam files as an .ez archive, which reduces file clutter a lot (read the docs of the `code` module).
That's as close as you get to "single executable" with the standard toolchain, but it works fairly well and across all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

There has been [Stand Alone Erlang](http://www.sics.se/~joe/sae.html) for a while, but I'm not sure of the status of it - I suspect is it not particulary productionised or in wide use (despite Joe Armstrong writing it). You would do well to Google it a bit more..

Comment: I checked this but on the web site they say that the Windows Installer is not working yet.