# Install-less NoSQL database with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I'm creating a new ASP.NET web application.  I'm thinking I'd like to use a NoSQL database such as CouchDB or MongoDB (or something else).  But, the web app will be hosted on multiple environments that I don't control.  I don't want to have to force the installers of this web app to have to install and configure some NoSQL database.

Ideally, I want to deploy all the pieces as part of my ASP.NET application.  This is similar to how [SQL Server Compact](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is deployed.  Are there any NoSQL databases out there that support this kind of deployment?

Comment: maybe try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603482/zero-deployment-couchdb-embedded-in-a-windows-app/6634320#6634320

Comment: @bvmou thanks for the link, but that documentation still makes it look like an installer gets run on the server.  From what I can tell both CouchDB and MongoDB require an install.

Comment: It can be rolled into your installer, if I correctly understand this: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Quirks_on_Windows

Comment: I don't want to have an installer.  I just want to do a standard "xcopy" deploy of an ASP.NET web app.  SQLite or SQL Server Compact allow me to do this.  I was wondering if there was a NoSQL equivalent.

Comment: Yeah I looked at that one too.  RavenDB has the ability to be installed as a separate web app, which is close to what I'm looking for.  But still overly complicated compared to SQLite.  Plus RavenDB still seems a bit too "new" for my liking. :-)

Comment: Maybe your app use a cloud-based database instance, instead of a db installed on the same server? If so take a look at cloudant.com or iriscouch.com for CouchDB; mongohq.com for MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to run RavenDB as an embedded .NET application, check out [Embedding RavenDB into an ASP.NET MVC 3 Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547101.aspx).

Comment: Huh, that's great.  I didn't see that in the RavenDB documentation for some reason.  This looks like the best fit for what I'm looking for.

Comment: mmm...licencing options for ravendb for closed source projects seems pricey.