# Starting application with Erlang

Tags: erlang

I would like to write a standalone Erlang application which could be run just like any other program (by clicking on .exe executable). Something like Wings3D does.

How can I do it ? What is the best approach to make it possible ? I am on Windows platform, if it is important.

**2nd UPDATE:**

Well, I haven't exported the `promodb:start/0` function and that was the reason Erlang could'n start (and, as the Muzaaya Joshua says, `werl -s` does not work). But now, I have another strange problem. In my `rebar.config` I have 2 dependencies:

```
{deps, [
            {cowboy, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/extend/cowboy.git"}},
            {erlydtl, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/evanmiller/erlydtl.git"}}
        ]
}.
```

and after I start Erlang using

```
erl -pa ebin deps/cowboy/ebin deps/erlydtl/ebin deps/proper/ebin -s promodb
```

I find by application:which_application() that only Cowboy is started:

```
[{cowboy,"Small, fast, modular HTTP server.","0.4.0"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.18"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.15"}]
```

As far as I know, Erlang should start all needed applications that I put in my `promodb.app` file, as:

```
{application, promodb,
 [
    {description, ""},
    {vsn, "0.1"},
    {registered, [promodb_sup]},
    {applications, [
                  kernel,
                  stdlib,
                  cowboy,
                  erlydtl
                 ]},
    {mod, { promodb, []}},
    {env, []}
 ]}.
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: There's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795628/erlang-compilation-erlang-as-stand-alone-executeable  It has a link to this guide that may help you: http://www.sics.se/~joe/sae.html

Comment: Thank you for that link, I've seen it already. Doesn't help much since its development stopped. But as you see, I have another, much simpler problem stil unresolved: how to start Erlang with arbitrary application on Windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `rebar escriptize` to pack a standalone package like rebar. Then you can use `./PackageName` in linux or `escript.exe PackageName` in windows.

Comment: Thanks for that, I haven't know rebar has such command. Unfortunatelly, in my case it doesn't work. I got error: escript: exception error: undefined function promodb:main/1 (although, I even added such function in promodb module).

Comment: Hi, I have `{escript_incl_apps, []}. {escript_emu_args, "%%! -smp auto\n"}.` in my rebar.config, this may help you. You can also check http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html , see how to pack your files to a standalone escript package.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create a release package and a boot script as explained in the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html#boot).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure if it solves the whole problem. After making a release, I should have full Erlang system with my application, ready to deploy, but I still don't have a standalone program. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `-s` option works everywhere. Just use `erl` NOT <strike>`werl`</strike>. The `werl` command attempts to load a GUI on Windows.
The [BitRock Install Builder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/download-step-2.html) is a great tool you need to check out. [Yaws Web Server](http://yaws.hyber.org) written in Erlang, uses it and many other applications.

Comment: Well, apparently, neither werl or erl works. With erl -s I got the same error, just in the standard cmd prompt.

Comment: `erl -s mnesia`  will start erlang shell and start mnesia along with it. Remember, if you have an application called: `myapp` , and it has a module say: `myapp.erl` then let the function that starts your whole application be: `start/0` so that you will just do: `erl -s myapp`

Answer (score 1):

Erlydtl doesn't have an application behaviour, it works like a library. As you can see in erlydtl examples, no app is needed to be started.

https://github.com/evanmiller/erlydtl#template-compilation

Check this:

erl -pa ebin deps/*/ebin

1> erlydtl:compile(<<"{{ foo }}">>, my_module_name).

Does it works?

I like  escriptize rebar option to create executables.